# getBytes() и русские символы - Java

Tags: java, строки, кодировка

Столкнулся с проблемой в примере из книги Шилда :

```
public class ByteArrayInputReset {
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String tmp = "abc"; // - Проблема ТУТ
    byte buf[] = tmp.getBytes();

    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {
        int c;
        while ((c=in.read()) !=-1){
            if (i==0){
                System.out.print((char) c);
            }else {
                System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase((char)c));
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        in.reset();
    }
}

}
```

Суть в том, что если я ввожу английские символы в строку tmp, то на консоль все выводится как положено, Но если вводим русские символы (или строки), то на выходе получаем:

> Ð°Ð±Ð².

```
byte buf[] = tmp.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Так пробовал разные кодировки, не помогло.

Думаю важно добавить - работаю в intellij idea 2018, настройки - File Enkoding 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стандартный вывод - sout работает как надо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но вот при использовании метода tmp.getBytes(); и русских символов, буфер забивается (непонятной) кодировкой и соответственно извлекается ересь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

повторюсь, при использовании анг. символов все отрабатывает как надо.

Объясните пожалуйста как добиться правильного вывода и в чем ошибка?

Comment: Зачем такое мудрить, выводтите символы по одному или всю строчку целиком.

Comment: Всё зависит от системной кодировки. А в винде всё усугубляется тем, что в командной строке кодировка отличная от системной. Русская кодировка windows-1251. В командной строке dos-866 (не помню как в жаве называется. может cp866). Вот и подбирай что сработает.

Comment: код сам по себе некорректный. Русские буквы что в utf8, что в utf16 занимают два байта, попытка как-то с ними побайтно работать дает те результаты, которые дает.